# Why does my Button style object only work on the text within the button and not the entire button?

Tags: button, swiftui

I have below a `ButtonStyle` object that I wish to use when a `Button` is tapped. However, when I call it on my `Button`, the effect is seen only on the text within the button and not on the entire `Button` as a whole.
I have tried calling it outside but to no avail. Can someone please explain to me how I can fix my error?

```
Button(action: {

    }) {
        Text("Button")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }.background(Color.red)
     .buttonStyle(ScaleButtonStyle())


struct ScaleButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 5 : 1)
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
Button(action: {}) {
            Text("Button")
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.title)
        }
        .buttonStyle(ScaleButtonStyle(bgColor: Color.red))
        .frame(width: geo.size.width*0.8, height: geo.size.height*0.1, alignment: .center)
        .background(Color.red)
        .clipShape(Rectangle())


struct ScaleButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
 let bgColor: Color

 func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
    configuration.label
        .background(bgColor)
        .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 5 : 1)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to make background as part of a button style as shown below.

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image]

```
struct ScaleButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let bgColor: Color
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .background(bgColor)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 5 : 1)
    }
}

struct TestScaleButtonStyle: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { }) {
            Text("Button")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }.buttonStyle(ScaleButtonStyle(bgColor: Color.red))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, but unfortunately the code still only makes the Text view within the button view to zoom, not the entire frame of the button itself.

Edit: have edited the question to reflect code with your suggested ButtonStyle struct

Comment: @mogoco8594, the `scaleEffect`, as well as any other geometry effect, does not change view's layout frame, so any such modifications will affect only presentation of button, not layout.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realise that, thanks for the explanation